# Is it acceptable practice to add methods to the Rails::Application subclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, standards

I was thinking about being able to add an "application name" method to my Rails::Application subclass, since the method that I had originally added to a helper for ApplicationController is no longer visible to my ActionMailer.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `app_name' for #<#<Class:0x44aba18>:0x449b8f0>
```

I haven't seen any reference to doing this in the standard rails tutorials, and a few Google queries don't indicate best or even acceptable practice.

I'd rather not have to hard code a lot of global application settings that may be of value in the mailer templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do it 'externally' in your application config, then the dependency is lightweight, and it's on you to maintain it with new rails releases. If for some reason you're nervous, you can put it in a `lib`, but that will probably feel more awkward for obvious reasons.

I am of the camp that will extend a primative class, like String, if the application very-widely uses the new method.  Some people will not; the most common argument I've heard is 'memory concerns' – which I can never make sense in light of the case of widespread usage in the app.

Comment: Is it "safe" to add it to the class definition in application.rb?

Comment: as long as you know what you're doing, yes :)

Comment: Well I guess that's my concern, I don't actually know what I'm doing. I know what I want to do, not how to do it. I'm sure I'm not the first person that would like a global property available to my ActionMailer view. Should I "add" the method through an initialiser instead?

Comment: You're hooking this into the Rails app itself, so its better to put it in the block in `application.rb`, or in its own module that defines stuff into the App. If this only needs to be used by ActuonMailer, then consider adding it there to limit the potential impact, changes in the 'rails API', etc.

Comment: I think an initializer is not the right approach because you already have `application.rb` which initializes the rails app

Comment: If I were to put this in my own module (is this "monkey-patching"?), where should I put it? Is this a case where I should just stick it into 'lib'?

Comment: If it is just one method definition (or a couple), you should put it in `application.rb`

Comment: thanks for the help. As a rails newbie I'm surprised there isn't something in the tutorials concerning this. Since it seems obvious to me that most projects require at least a few globally available settings that aren't "stock".

Comment: 'global' settings are common, but less-so when the requirement is that they extend the base Rails app in some way.  Most people just put data in Constants.

Comment: Even though you have given me an answer, I'd like to know where you recommend the constants be put (so that they are globally-accessible).

Comment: Constants often go in the related `environment.rb` file, or in an initializer if there is other things in context (not just  one Constant)